# Select thread to interact with Java

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, user-interaction

So I have a socket situation where I have a multithread server that receive X number of connections and manage all of them (I use this code to base mine: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Network-Protocol/AmultithreadedSocketServer.htm). That's not completely my code but I used that as a base for the multithreading:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class EchoServer {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ServerSocket m_ServerSocket = new ServerSocket(12111);
    int id = 0;
    while (true) {
      Socket clientSocket = m_ServerSocket.accept();
      ClientServiceThread cliThread = new ClientServiceThread(clientSocket, id++);
      cliThread.start();
    }
  }
}

class ClientServiceThread extends Thread {
  Socket clientSocket;
  int clientID = -1;
  boolean running = true;

  ClientServiceThread(Socket s, int i) {
    clientSocket = s;
    clientID = i;
  }

  public void run() {
    System.out.println("Accepted Client : ID - " + clientID + " : Address - "
        + clientSocket.getInetAddress().getHostName());
    try {
      BufferedReader   in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
      PrintWriter   out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream()));
      while (running) {
        String clientCommand = in.readLine();
        System.out.println("Client Says :" + clientCommand);
        if (clientCommand.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) {
          running = false;
          System.out.print("Stopping client thread for client : " + clientID);
        } else {
          out.println(clientCommand);
          out.flush();
        }
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that all those clients connected to me are waiting a response from the user which provide that response using keyboard input (BufferedReader SYSTEM_IN = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); )  But I need to list all the threads that I have opened and select manually the one that I want to interact with. How can I do that??

So for example to the first socket I want to send `foo` and `faa` to the second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think you need to create an application where you can reply to **Specific** client like in a chat application.

I will provide some suggestions you could try out. In a real environment what we do in a chat is, send reply to a person using their own chat window. That means we use some kind of an ID to identify **who we talk with**.

You can do the same in the given scenario. you can use `clientID` to identify required client who you need to reply. But first you will have to MAP **client ID** to the client's identity details such as Socket, IP and PORT. [ You can have threads to handle client's incoming messages separately]

Use hash map to do the mapping [ http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html ] and use Unique client ID's so you will not get any collisions. And As Value of the hash Map store client details [Socket , IP and PORT] in a structure like object.

Whenever you need to reply to a client use a separate **Reply** function which will send message to the specific client using Socket details extracted from Hash Map. And main point of the answer :

> you will have to specify which client you need to reply to [In a
>   console application Provide client ID as first word or what ever
>   mechanism].

Please ask for any clarification I will try my best to answer